# Big Merge / Memory management

Tags: r, memory-management, merge, data.table

I've hit a wall trying to merge a large file and a smaller one. I have [read](https://www.google.com/search?q=r%20cannot%20allocate%20vector%20of%20size&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=) [many](http://www.matthewckeller.com/html/memory.html) other posts about memory management in R, and haven't been able to find a non-extreme (go 64bit, upload to a cluster, etc) method of resolving it. I've tried a bit with the bigmemory package, but not been able to find a solution. I thought I'd try here before I throw my hands up in frustration.

The code I'm running is like the below:

```
#rm(list=ls())
localtempdir<- "F:/Temp/"
memory.limit(size=4095)
[1] 4095
    memory.size(max=TRUE)
[1] 487.56
gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 170485  4.6     350000   9.4   350000   9.4
Vcells 102975  0.8   52633376 401.6 62529185 477.1

client_daily<-read.csv(paste(localtempdir,"client_daily.csv",sep=""),header=TRUE)
object.size(client_daily)
>130MB

sbp_demos<-read.csv(paste(localtempdir,"sbp_demos",sep=""))
object.size(demos)
>0.16MB
client_daily<-merge(client_daily,sbp_demos,by.x="OBID",by.y="OBID",all.x=TRUE)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.0 MB
```

I guess I'm asking are there any clever ways around this which don't involve buying new hardware?

1. I need to be able to `merge` to create a bigger object.
2. I'll then need to be doing regressions etc with that bigger object.

Should I give up? Should bigmemory be able to help solve this?

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

> Details:  R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08) Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386
>   (32-bit) Intel 2 Duo Core @2.33GHz, 3.48GB RAM

Comment: Have you looked at `data.table` package? It is *fast* for large merges, and coincidentally may be more memory efficient to boot?

Comment: This will probably not solve your problem, but here is something you can try.  If there are any columns in either data set which you do not need: remove them after reading the data in, perform a gc(), and then try the merge again.  Another idea is to convert your data to a matrix if possible, as they tend to use up less memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Chase already mentioned, you can try [data.table](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/datatable/) or perhaps [sqldf](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/).

For either one, you will likely get more juice out of it if you set the indexes appropriately.

With data.table you would:

```
dt1 <- data.table(sbp_demos, key='OBID')
dt2 <- data.table(client_daily, key='OBID')

## Do an INNER JOIN-like operation, where non-matching rows are removed
mi <- dt1[dt2, nomatch=0]

## Do a RIGHT JOIN(?)-like operation ... all rows in dt2 will be returned.
## If there is no matching row in dt1, the values in the dt1 columns for
## the merged row will be NA
mr <- dt1[dt2]
```

If you go the `sqldf` route, [look at example 4i on its website](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) ... again, make sure you use indexes correctly.